# How to change the default endpoint of an azure vm?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have create a new linux virtual machine on azure abcxyz.cloudapp.net.
I have a webapp running on non standard port 12320.
When a user goes to http://abcxyz.coudapp.net, how can I point it to http://abcxyz.cloudapp.net:12320?

Comment: This belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow. But... did you look at your VM's endpoint settings? If so, you'd see the current mapping of external to internal port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question for ServerFault. But it's trivial (and you should have seen it if you looked at your VM's endpoint settings): Just change the internal port mapping of your endpoint from 80 to 12320.

Comment: Where can I change the internal ip mapping of my endpoint from 80 to 12320? Is this something that can be done from azure portal ?

Comment: Yes, in the portal. Seriously, you need to actually try. You showed no work in your question. There is a ton of documentation on creating Azure endpoints. In fact, there are probably at least a dozen other questions on StackOverflow where the answers show how to create endpoints.